# How to implement those tables please

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to implement the tables below

[image]

[image]
I know I can use custome cell with two labels but any idea how to implement the overall shape with the vertical and horizontal labels

Comment: So, the idea here is that you have your standard tableview, and create the cells in a way the will have sections, etc. so that you have the horizontal labels. The vertical labels might be additional uiviews.

Comment: yes exactly that what I want to do

Comment: Do it then :D Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe set up a regular view controller. Then add a collection view, make the cell very large. In that collection view cell add a label on the side (this will become the light blue box). Then right next to it add a table view with sections.  The header would be the red and dark blue area.

This would work, but you need the flexibility of starting as a view controller, and doing the collection and table view through delegates

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad and cannot be answered in such form.

It's a customized `UITableView` created by Subclass-ing the `UITableViewCell`.

Check these tutorials and third-party controls:

1. [Horizontal TableView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)
2. [MDSpreadViewDemo](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadViewDemo)
3. [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView)